# Why the same function behaves differently after linking other object files?

Tags: c, r, openssl, rcpp

I am handling a bug of a R extension which only occurs on debian system.

The `SSL_CTX_new` function produces a **stack smashing detected** during runtime which might indicate an occurrence of segfault.

To understand the bug, I write a standalone test function:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
RcppExport SEXP test() {
    BEGIN_RCPP

    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

    END_RCPP
}
```

This function run normally standalone.

However, after linking my existed project with the test function, it produces a **stack smashing detected**

Why the same function behaves differently after linking other object files? Could anyone give me some hints? Thanks!

---

Here is my project: https://github.com/wush978/RMessenger. It crashes on debian so far.

Answer (score 0):

R handles its own memory management. The Valgrind memory profiler / debugger has been used successfully before, and there are some posts on the web.

If I understand your posts correctly, then the SSL routine may be doing something that upsets R.  You will have to debug that.  What you have posted here does not constitute a reproducible bug report.

You may also find the feedback you could get on the rcpp-devel list helpful.

Comment: But `SSL_CTX_new` runs normally with R and Rcpp, so I guess the problem is the conflict between the function and `libstrophe`.

Comment: So what was the fix?  I see you have a new version on CRAN, please share details and follow-up here.

Comment: I removed all existed files in _libstrophe_ first, and the `SSL_CTX_new` ran normally. Then I added the `.c` files one by one until `SSL_CTX_new` produced _stack smashing detected_. Finally, I noticed that the file `libstrophe/sha1.c` is unecessary and makes `SSL_CTX_new` produce _stack smashing detected_. However, I still do not understand the side effect of linking.